# Ingreso seguro formulario login

Tags: php, sql-server, formularios, xampp, login

Intento hacer un login de manera segura, realice un documento PHP que realiza la conexión a la base de datos, ademas de comprobar si el administrador y la contraseña que digito el usuario son iguales a los que estan en la base de datos SQL Server.

Aqui esta mi codigo PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['btnAdmin'])) {  

    $Administrador = $_POST['AdminName'];
    $contrasena = $_POST['contrasena'];
    $sha1_pass = sha1($contrasena);  

    $serverName = "AFTIC004";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"UneteAlParche_BD", "UID"=>"codestack", "PWD"=>"jrdLpWad5ik3rFWatjLQ" );
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if ($conn == true) {
        echo "Conexión exitosa. <br><br>";
    }else{
        echo "Conexión incorrecta. <br><br>";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        return false;
    }

    $consulta = "SELECT Nombre FROM sisAdministrador WHERE Nombre = '$Administrador' AND Password = '$contrasena'";
    $params = array(1, $Administrador,$contrasena,3);
    $resultado= sqlsrv_query($conn, $consulta, $params);

    if (sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        echo "Consulta erronea. <br><br>";
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        return false;
        close($conn);   
    }else{
        echo "Admin correcto. <br><br>"; 
        header('location: VentanaReportesAdminIngresado.html');
        return true;
    }   
}
?>
```

Y el formulario:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ventanaReportes.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="VentanaReportes.js"></script>
    <title>¡Unete al parche! - Reportes Administrador</title>

</head>
<body>
    <header id="principal1">
        <span id="tituloAdmin">
            <h3>Ventana Reportes Administrador - ¡Unete al parche!</h3>
        </span>
    </header>
    <br>
    <div id="box">
        <img src="https://unetealparche.fusagasugadigital.gov.co/Images/UneteAlParche3.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
        <br></br>
        <aside id="columna">
            <a href="https://unetealparche.fusagasugadigital.gov.co/Default", id="link" class="button">P&aacute;gina principal</a>
        </aside>
        <aside id="columna1">
            <a href="file:///C:/Users/jdmorales/Documents/3%20-%20Plataforma%20Unete%20al%20parche/Ventana%20reportes/VentanaReportes.html", id="link" class="button">Home</a>
        </aside>
        <br>
    </div>
    <div id="box1">
        <textarea name="mensaje" rows="6" id="texto" readonly="readonly" disabled="disabled">Esta ventana es exclusiva para los administradores de la plataforma, tenga en cuenta que los administradores tienen m&aacute;s privilegios que los usuarios regulares.Para garantizar una mejor funcionalidad de protecci&oacute;n a la privacidad y evitar inconvenientes entre los administradores y los usuarios le pediremos que se registre para poder acceder y verificar su rol como administrador. Si usted es usuario regular el ingreso sera fallido.

Si usted es administrador por favor digite la informaci&oacute;n solicitada en el siguiente formulario:
        </textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="box2">
        <img src="C:/Users/jdmorales/Pictures/user_icon.png" alt="ImagenAdministrador" id="img">
        <form name="LoginAdmin" method="post" action="validar.php" class="login" id="formulario" onsubmit="return validacion()">
            <label><b>Nombre Administrador*: </b><br></label>
            <input type="text" id="AdminName" name="AdminName" placeholder="&#128272;Ingrese su nombre">
            <br><br>
            <label><b>Contrase&ntilde;a*: </b><br></label>
            <input type="password" id="contrasena" name="contrasena" placeholder="&#128272;ej: 1234**">
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Entrar" name="btnAdmin" class="button">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<hr>
<footer>
    <div  id="footer" style="left: 10px; bottom: 5px;">
        <p>&copy; 2019 - Alcald&iacute;a de Fusagasug&aacute;</p>   
    </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

La consulta funciona, me asegure de eso en mi SQL server Management Studio, pero no se donde esta la falla. Ayuda por fa, necesito encontrar la solucion a este problema. Verifica la conexión y aparentemente entra, el problema es que no hay seguridad de nada. Con ingresar cualquier cosa en los input accede a otra pagina re-direccionada. He buscado en muchas paginas informacion, pero todos tienen que ver con MySQL, y en mi poca experiencia se que ambos son muy diferentes, les pido ayuda, no espero ningun otro tipo de respuesta

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es muy importante que leas esos enlaces. No es tu primer pregunta, y el sistema puede bloquearte si las publicaciones que haces no son de calidad, y si no aceptas las respuestas correctas que te dieron. Aparte de ello, A que te referis con que no hay seguridad? que es lo que hace el sistema para que digas esos?

Comment: `if (sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultado))` si es true, osea que los valores enviados en tu formulario son los corectos le dices que es in correcto, pero si es False osea que los datos sin incorrectos le estas diciendo que es correcto. xD

Comment: Oye gbianchi♦, con el debido respeto que te mereces, de un desconocido a otro, realmente no me importa tener una medalla por preguntar, lo unico que quiero es una solucion a mis problemas, para eso es este sitio web no? Medallas? Con eso arreglo mi problema? no, y si me bloquean pues busco otros medios de ayuda, ademas considerame, tal vez seas muy inteligente con respecto a estos temas, yo no. Entonces como tu sabes mas que yo te dare un consejo, aceptarlo o no es tu decision, si tienes conocimiento de un tema ayuda a un compañero si no, pues no hagas nada. Simple. Solo quiero soluciones y ya